# iOS Segue not working as expected when passing value

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a button with the following code:

```
@IBAction func buttonPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("newAccount", sender: sender)
}
```

When the button is pressed it performs a segue. I want to pass a value to the new view controller so I added the following code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "newAccount" {
        if let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as? NewAccountViewController {
            dvc.testValue = "This is my test value I want to pass"
        }
    }
}
```

The NewAccountViewController doesn't receive the value (I don't get any error).

The code I have in my NewAccountViewController is:

```
var testValue:String?
```

When I print(testValue) I don't get anything.

Why isn't this working as expected?

Comment: Have you checked that you set the class of destinationViewController to `NewAccountViewController` in storyboard ?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on `dvc.testValue` to see if it's being executed? Maybe the `if let` fails, or the case of `segue.identifier` is different. You shouldn't need to test the identifier on the assumption the `if let` will only work for the right VC.

Comment: @Michael It looks like the if let part fails. I added print("test if let") to the if let statement and it does not print.

Comment: @Leo I am not sure I follow. How can I confirm that?

Comment: So as @Leo points out, you probably haven't set the class of the VC.

Comment: @user1822824 See the image I post below.

Comment: your `if segue.identifier == "newAccount"` is satisfied , if yes `if let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as? NewAccountViewController` condition is statisfied or not

Comment: @Leo Thanks. That fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the class is set correctly

Like the `ViewController` in below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are maybe two reasons: 1. identifier is not set as "newAccount" in the storyboard; 2. you have put a navigator view controller into the NewAccountViewController, which would ask you to transfer the destination as UINavigationController instead of NewAccountViewController. Hope this helps.